# How to manage to solve for the scale of factor increase between two galaxies?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, space-expansion, redshift

The greatest redshift known corresponds to the cosmic microwave background
(CMB, CBR) at redshift z  1100 (although the redshift is obtained theoretically
rather than observationally). UDFy-38135539 is a galaxy with the high redshift of
z = 8:555. By what factor did the volume of the universe increase between the
epochs corresponding to z = 1100 and z = 8:555?

Answer (score 0):

The scale factor

a(t) = 1/(1+z) and linear dimensions go like a, volume like $a^3$

Since the a factor change is about 100 (approximating, you can do it exactly), the volume factor would be a million to 1

See the equation for a at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerating_expansion_of_the_universe
In the Supernova Observation section. It's in other wiki articles and in any good cosmology book like Dodelson

Comment: okay so the below is correct:

Comment: r(t) =1/1+1101, for the 3 dimensional universe 1/1101*1/1101*1/1101= 1/3346322. this means that at the epoch corresponding to z= 1100 the universe 1/3346322 increased than the epoch coresspondinng to z = 8.555

Comment: Don't follow your algebra. One is 1/1102, the other 1/9.555, the ratios are 1102/9.555 approximately 100. Cube it for volume. That would be how much the volume increased. Your 1/etc makes no sense to me. Maybe if you write it algebraically correct.

Comment: many thanks Bob, as i mentioned i am really new to the cosmology studies and really i gives me hard time to connect all the pieces together.

Comment: Sure, no problem.  It takes a while, worse than learning how to ride a bycicle when you were a child. Dodelson is a nice cosmology book, may assume you know some general relativity. Feel free to ask as you go along in your studies, just careful with homework problems, the site wants you to do some work before you ask.

Comment: many thanks Bob for your kind support. sure will take in consideration your advice.